# Get what is the closest place

Tags: javascript

I'm building an app and I need to know how to get what is the closest place based on my location.
I have this code to get my location:

```
var userLatitude;
var userLongitude
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
console.log(`${userLatitude} ${userLongitude}`);
});
```

And different places in 'objects', for example:

```
var place1= {
   name: 'place1',
   latitude: '-20',
   longitude: '-30'
}
var place2= {
   name: 'place2',
   latitude: '-30',
   longitude: '-19'
}
```

I need a function or something to get what is the closest place based on my location. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't use ":" in javascript(you use in in typescript), please use "=" like so:

```
var place1 = {
    name: 'place1',
    latitude: '-20',
    longitude: '-30'
}
var place2 = {
    name: 'place2',
    latitude: '-30',
    longitude: '-19'
}
```

To use latitude and longitude of place you access it like this, make calculations for yourself with this knowledgde, but be carefull of where on the Earth are you calculating distace from (e.g east to west etc.)

```
//latitude and longtitude of place1
console.log(place1.latitude)
console.log(place1.longitude)
//latitude and longtitude of place2
console.log(place2.latitude)
console.log(place2.longitude)
```